# CSS drop down positioning problems in IE7

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

I've been trying to figure this out all morning and I just can't get anywhere with it.

I'm working on this website for a client and the dropdown menu just will not position properly in IE7. I have it working in everything else (even IE6!) but IE7 just will not play ball.

If there is anyone that could help that would be awesome!

The page(s) are at http://adriantrimble.com/mbf

[Correct http://adriantrimble.com/correct.jpg](http://adriantrimble.com/correct.jpg)

[IE7 http://adriantrimble.com/ie7.jpg](http://adriantrimble.com/ie7.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Just drop support for IE on your website (if only we could!). ;-)

Comment: Its funny you mentioned that. My colleague went to present this site to the client yesterday and the menu was all over the place in the clients browser, which was IE6. Thus, the hasty re-do of the menu.

Thanks to Sir David of Lee and Mathachew! Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try changing the subnav class so that the 'top' declaration has an actual number value instead of just 'auto'

So maybe something like this...

```
.subnav { left:auto; top:59px; }
```

Comment: This is close. You need to add top: 59px, but the left should be a defined pixel value since auto doesn't place it exactly where it needs to go. 0 will put it slightly to the left of where it falls when using auto in other browsers and IE8, so possibly left: 8px or so.

Comment: Good point, for some reason I missed in the example that if was off on the left as well.

Comment: left: 0 works just fine, if its a few pixels off it doesn't matter, so long as it's under the top menu item and not way off to the right, I'm happy!